# Formatting SQL expressions for ArcPy with ArcSDE for PostgreSQL feature class?

Tags: arcpy, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, error-000358

I'm trying to use SelectLayerByAttribute to find the last point added to a FC.  I figured I could use the objectid field because it's serial.  I wrote the following:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("controller", "NEW_SELECTION", """ "OBJECTID" = (SELECT MAX("OBJECTID") FROM controller) """)
```

following the notes on found [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000)

However, I get the following error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6494, in
>   SelectLayerByAttribute     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid
>   expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

I'm using a Postgres geodatabase and I know all the db's require slightly different formatting requirements.  This one I can't figure out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names aren't escaped as far as I know in Postgres. Try

```
 'OBJECTID = (SELECT MAX(OBJECTID) FROM controller)'
```

as your where clause.

Comment: .. and use AddFieldDelimiters to compose queries without worrying for the underlying DBMS syntax http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000006p000000